# Create a VM from snapshot use /dev/VDA instead /dev/SDA

Tags: openstack, libvirt

0

We have an OpenStack instance configured with multiple images, including CentOS, Redhat, and Ubuntu. When creating a new instance, the root partition attaches as SCSI without any issues. All images are correctly set to use the appropriate drivers.

However, a problem arises when generating a snapshot from a running instance and then creating a new server using this volume snapshot. In this scenario, the root partition appears as "/dev/vda". The more troublesome situation occurs when a new volume is attached, which then appears as "/dev/sda". This new volume becomes the main disk, leading to complications during server reboot as it can't locate a valid boot partition.

We need a solution to this issue. Currently, the workaround involves adding metadata to the flavors: specifically, setting "boot_menu=true". This addition causes a "Press ESC for boot menu" message to appear in the console. While this provides a manual option to select the correct boot disk (VDA), it's not an ideal fix.

I've attempted to apply the metadata value to the flavor, but I'm unsure how to set it as the default for snapshots. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
$ openstack flavor set --property hw:scsi_model=virtio-scsi zzzz-zzz-zzz-zzz
$ openstack flavor set --property hw:disk_bus=scsi zzzz-zzz-zzz-zzz
```

Do you have any suggestions or recommendations for resolving this issue?

---

Edit: posible solution but looking for one using a different approach.

Identified a possible parameter can be added to nova compute nodes :

```
[libvirt]
disk_prefix=sd
```

This will force to libvirt attach new disk devices using /dev/sdX
It is documented here:

https://docs.openstack.org/ocata/config-reference/compute/config-options.html

I prefer to use some kind of metadata to avoid global side effects changing this setting globally.

---

Edit 2:
This solution only solves the different letters for VDA and SDA, but the second volume attached still acts as boot device.

---

Edit 3:

After reading the documentation, all my problems can be solved if the user can create an image associated with the volume snapshot.

Glance provides two kinds of images: normal images (qcow/iso) and "snapshot" images. The first one is stored on glance storage and the second one is associated with the volume snapshot (cinder), form the point of view or glance, there is no real difference, it stores the properties on database and apply it when you create a new instance.

The problem in my case is that a normal user has no permission to create images. The glance-policy specifies the add-image role only for admins.

```json
{
    "add_image": "role:admin",
...
}
```

Glance doesn't allow grant permissions only to add "snapshot images" to users.

Based on this, the default server creation without an image associated is not clear how to set those properties (disk driver basically) and if it is possible or not. My first idea was to set it using the flavor, but it is not working either.

Comment: Would it help to add the same metadata for the volume snapshot as well? In the cli it would be:`openstack volume snapshot set --property hw_scsi_model=virtio-scsi --property hw_disk_bus=scsi <VOL_SNAP>
`. Or have you tried that already?

Answer (score 0):

As already [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76963146/create-a-vm-from-snapshot-use-dev-vda-instead-dev-sda/76969267?noredirect=1#comment135728177_76969267), you can use image metadata:

```
root@control01:~# openstack image set --property hw_scsi_model=virtio-scsi --property hw_disk_bus=scsi <IMAGE>
root@control01:~# openstack image show <IMAGE> -c properties -f json | jq '.properties|.["hw_disk_bus", "hw_scsi_model"]'
"scsi"
"virtio-scsi"
```

Creating an instance from that image should have `/dev/sda` as root device (independent of ephemeral disk or persistent volume). Creating a volume snapshot should inherit those properties, launching an instance from that snapshot also inherits them as do all attached volumes. I could verify with Openstack version Victoria.
If the snapshot does not have the image properties inherited, you might need to check why that is, maybe some glance or cinder policy? But IIRC this did already work properly for us in Ocata, and it still does in Victoria. I don't have a newer release available yet. If you turn on debug logs for cinder and glance you might see why the properties are not set.

Comment: In my case, the users have no permission to create images, they boot from volume snapshots and don't inherit those image properties. For some reason to attach a second volume, the new ones is  the boot volume.

Comment: I just tried a few other attempts (I only have Victoria available) with a non-admin user in a non-admin project and the image properties are inherited to the volume snapshot, and attaching more volumes works as expected (all are attached with /dev/sd* letter). If I restrict the "add_image" to the admin role only, I can't even create a volume snapshot. How is it possible that you can?

Comment: I'm not sure how it is configured, but you can try deleting the image and keeping the volume snapshot